# Is there any point to sync shot other than marking enemies?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

Does using Sync Shot make you do more damage or is it just to help sort through the chaos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When playing with human teammates, it makes it easy to assign kills to each squad member for coordinated take-downs.

When playing with AI teammates, it's a much more functional feature. You can assign a shot to each AI squad mate (depending on how many upgrades you have for the sync shot skill). Then, you have two options for commanding them to take their shots:

1. They will immediately take their shots as soon as you shoot a target. This allows you to make your own kill along with your squad at the same time.
2. You can hold down the button you use to mark enemies. This will instruct your squad to immediately take their shots. This allows you to have them fire even if you do not have your own target. It also gives you an opportunity to stay in the drone when ordering them to engage enemies.

Sync shot offers no damage bonus. However, the game is exceptionally forgiving with your AI teammates' accuracy and line-of-sight. Using sync shot can, at times, be a bit of a cheat. Your AI teammates can make shots that would be impossible for you. They're often able to see and fire through perimeter walls and between buildings. They also have no problem with even extreme range. The only time they seem to always lose line-of-sight is when their target is inside a building.

Edit:
Another god-tier power of your AI squad mates when using sync shot is that they are guaranteed to kill their target if they don't miss. It's very rare that they miss, and really that only happens if their target moves into a building at the moment they take their shot. Otherwise, if they have line-of-sight, they will always kill their target in that one shot.